# Crash Jetbrains ide with Yosemite Mac osX (Webstorm, intellij)

Tags: java, eclipse, jetbrains-ide, osx-yosemite

This is a tip in reference to Yosemite ´s users (10.10). Yosemite erase 1.6 apple jdk and install 1.7, but JAVA´s IDE for example Intellij or Eclipse needs 1.6, if you haven´t reinstalled this version, your ide will crash at the beginning... after this process you can configure your ide with 1.7 version.

Here the link : [Apple JDK 1.6](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please do not edit your Info.plist file as it will [break the application digital signature and prevent the patch updates](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/27854363-IDE-doesn-t-start-after-updating-to-Mac-OS-Yosemite-or-Mavericks).

I was able to get phpStorm working properly again on my Mac ( Yosemite ) by installing this apple support package: [Java for OS X 2014-001Java](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572)

This package installs the same version of Java 6 included in Java for OS X 2013-005 which apparently plays nice with JetBrains.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Java 6 is deprecated on all recent OS X versions.
Using it makes your Mac vulnerable to well known security issues.

Neither Apple nor Oracle are providing security updates for Java 6 on OS X.

Comment: Unfortunately, those of us who need to use this software for our livelihood do not have much choice until JetBrains updates their software.

Comment: Somehow it is a very difficult situation, because in many larger companies IT security policies disalow the usage of ancient Java 6 runtimes. 
Oracle sells still quarterly updated security patched Java-6 versions, but AFAIK Apple is not deploying these security patches to Mac users. At the end of the day a crashing IDE is better as a hacked Mac. :-(

Comment: @JoergRuethschilling, could you send me a link to where I may purchase a security-patched Java-6 version that will be what need on my Mac?  That would be the best solution to this question's problem anyway.

Comment: This did not work for me.  I've run the JRE 6 installer to no avail. PyCharm just reports "The application PyCharm is not open anymore."

Answer (score 31):

It's easy to change Jetbrains' products to use jdk1.7:

1. Open Application folder
2. Choose Jetbrains product you use
3. RightClick and choose 'show package content' <- I dont know how exactly it is in english version of OS
4. Choose Contents
5. Double Click `Info.plist`
6. Find:

   `<key>JVMVersion</key>
    <string>1.6*</string>`
7. and change to:

   `<key>JVMVersion</key>
    <string>1.7*</string>`
8. Save and quit,
9. Enjoy!

Comment: That worked great.  You can also edit the file from the terminal:  `$ nano "/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 13.app/Contents/Info.plist"`

Comment: people over at jetbrain [do not recommend](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/27854363-IDE-doesn-t-start-after-updating-to-Mac-OS-Yosemite-or-Mavericks) using version 1.7 for having several *critical issues*. In addition the discourage to modify Info.plist as it will prevent future updates. I'll better go for installing jdk 1.6

Comment: Per @Deoxyseia 's statement, yes it works with 1.8 as well but you must use `<string>1.8*</string>`.

Comment: it doesnt work. Updated to 1.8.45 and updated the JVMVersion and still webstorm doesnt start.

Answer (score 2):

Apple 1.6 is still required to run JetBrains IDEs. There should be a window with the suggestion to install Java when you start the product for the first time, but it could be hidden by other application windows.
See https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/27854363-IDE-doesn-t-start-after-updating-to-Mac-OS-Yosemite-or-Mavericks

Answer (score 0):

Since today, PHPStorm 9 comes with a special Yosemite version including JDK 1.8.

> This alternative PhpStorm 9 distribution bundles JDK 1.8 customized by the JetBrains team for better performance. Please note this non-default option may contain some issues.

No more issues with java...

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling `libpng` helped me after hours of tries and checking all possible causes:

```
brew uninstall --force libpng
brew install libpng
```

Tested on Mac OS X Sierra (10.12.1) with WebStorm 2016.2